# Successfully created records don't show up in SQL database

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

This code doesn't work for some reason. It says "record created successfully", but when I check the SQL DB the record doesn't show up for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<title>Voer gegevens in</title>
<body>
<?php
$serverName = "***";
$usr="*****";
$pwd="*****";
$db="********";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
// $con = require_once "db_config.php";
// koppeling met de database-server, gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord

if (!$con)
{
 die ("kon niet verbinden met: " . sqlsrv_connect_error());
}
echo "OK, er is verbinding met de server <br>";

$sql="INSERT INTO tblRelatie (fldNaam, fldPostcode, fldPlaats, fldAdres)     VALUES ('".$_POST['Naam']."','".$_POST['Postcode']."','".$_POST['Plaats']."','".$_POST['Adres']."';)";
sqlsrv_query($con,$sql);
// Tabelnaam en alle genoemde kolom-namen waarin de waarden vervolgens     worden geplaatst

if (!$con) { echo "error"; }
else { echo "1 record toegevoegd"; }
sqlsrv_close ($con);
?>
</html>
```

What might cause that and how do I resolve it?

Comment: No need to commit?

Comment: what is $_PO    ST['Adres']?? why space between PO and ST?

Comment: sorry first time asking something here i messed up when inserting the code.
also i commented some stuff cause i thought it was cousing issues

Comment: Learn to use PDO and don't use this horrible SQL-injection code. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: just need help with this code, not going to rewrite everything it will only be used internally and i'm going to be the only one fillinf in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking the return value from `sqlsrv_query`, so you're getting "success" when you should not be.  This is obscuring your ability to see what's really happening.

Change the lines to this to get the proper result:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) { echo "error: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); }
else { echo "1 record toegevoegd"; }
```

The actual error is that the INSERT statement is ill-formed, at the very end of the statement.  I assume that the invalid snippet `$_PO    ST['Adres']` is due to copy/paste error, however the real issue is immediately afterward.

This end of the statement:

```
$_POST['Adres']."';)";
```

should be changed to this:

```
$_POST['Adres']."');";
```

so that the statement terminator (`;`) appears *outside* the statement parenthesis.

Comment: OK, er is verbinding met de server 
error: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )

 this is the error i get

Comment: I had misspelled `$con` (as `$conn`) in my answer.  I have corrected that, and with that change, it should work for you.